# Changing Text via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a promotional products website and it's based on a third party template.  I am trying to use jQuery to change the word "from" to "As Low As" under the item when displayed.

I need help with the code to do so.

```
<div class="fr"><a href="https://www.promosplusva.com/product/Blizzard_Ice_Scraper_982306"><b>from</b><em>fr</em> $1.31</a></div>
```

I would like to change "from" to "as low as".

I have tried using

```
<script>
document.getElementById("fr").innerHTML = "As Low As";
</script>
```

That didnt work so I am reaching out for suggestions.

Comment: `$(".fr b").text( "As Low As" );`?

Comment: Welcome. Please [show what you've already tried](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and [any research you've done into how to solve it](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Comment: that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Eddie you missed anchor tag it should be $(".fr a b").text("As Low As")

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can select the div with the class of `fr`, find the `<b>` tag within that and use jQuery's [text](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method to alter the text as you see fit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.fr").find("b").text("As Low As");
});
```

I've wrapped it in a call to `$(document).ready(...)`, as it sounds like you don't have full control of the page and this will ensure that everything is loaded before attempting to manipulate the text.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192802/discussion-on-answer-by-james-hibbard-changing-text-via-jquery).